# how to update two different documents on mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I have follower and subscriber project and when a user follows other user, I should inc 1 to follower and inc 1 to subscriber's count

I use these codes to update,

this one is `k` which is follower's count,

```
$m->obarax->user->update(array("_id" => $_SESSION["u"]["_id"]),array('$inc' => array("k" => (int)1)));
```

this one is `t` which is subscriber's count,

```
$m->obarax->uye->update(array("_id" => new MongoId($_GET["idi"])),array('$inc' => array("t" => (int)1)));
```

the thing that bothers me that, I searched a lot, but I could not find a way to merge those two queries into one basic query, Is there a way so I can merge those queries ? thank you :)

Comment: You can't merge them since your updating two different keys on two different documents. Besides that, your collections also differ, but it still not possible even if you were using the same collection because your data will be de-normalized.

Comment: @Sagish: make that an answer

Comment: @SergioTulentsev everytime you are online :))

Comment: @gakmaku: I can't waste time on sleep when I can be helping you guys :)

Comment: Sleep is for the weak and tubby :P

Comment: @Sammaye sammaye is here too :)) nice :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have multikey posts which I call it **x** and when I get those posts with $in, and order them by their _id, I get **scanandorder => 1** I index those documents, **x_1__id_1** like this, how can I make, scanandorder 0 ? thank you :)

Comment: @gakmaku: make a proper question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't merge them since you're updating two different keys on two different documents. Besides that, your collections also differ, but it still not possible even if you were using the same collection because your data will be de-normalized in this case.